# Calculate difference between two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Trying to find an efficient algorithm that finds the difference between two sorted arrays while one of the arrays is always the subset of the other one.

For example, we can have two sorted arrays

- [1, 2, 3, 4]
- [1, 3, 4]

And the second array is a subset of the first one.

---

Potential Solution:
The most efficient algorithm I can think of is to iterate through the arrays simultaneously and compare the element since they are sorted. Another optimization is to create a counter of the difference in length between two arrays and if we have encountered the number of different elements that is equal to the difference we calculated at front, the algorithm can stop at that point.

Maybe this is the algorithm that is most efficient, but I would like to hear your guys' opinions.

Comment: Linear time is the best you can hope for asymptotically. Seems like your first approach is sound. I don't understand the second one.

Comment: First approach is straightforward; second one is most efficient as it shortcuts the first. In any case this is all linear time. Since you probably spent more time on the sort don't worry about this step :)

Comment: The second approach will be as bad as the first since finding the size of the two arrays essentially means you (or a library function) has counted the elements in a linear fashion.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the number of missing elements in the subset.

Eg. If exactly one number is missing, you can binary search for the missing number. Complexity is roughly O(log(n)). This is efficient compared to linear searching (O(n)).

In general, if k numbers are missing, you can probably find them in O(klogn) time. So as long as k is small, this is the efficient solution.